# TfLiteGpuDelegate Invoke: GpuDelegate must run on the same thread where it was initialized

Tags: android, tensorflow, image-segmentation, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to run a custom Tflie model for segmentation in Android. It runs fine on CPU but while using GPU delegate, it crashes with following error:-

```
E/AndroidRuntime(30867): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
E/AndroidRuntime(30867): Process: com.apptec.scansdk, PID: 30867
E/AndroidRuntime(30867): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
E/AndroidRuntime(30867):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
E/AndroidRuntime(30867):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
E/AndroidRuntime(30867):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
E/AndroidRuntime(30867):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
E/AndroidRuntime(30867):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
E/AndroidRuntime(30867):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
E/AndroidRuntime(30867):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
E/AndroidRuntime(30867):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
E/AndroidRuntime(30867): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Internal error: Failed to run on the given Interpreter: TensorDescriptor don't have selector with name - Slice
E/AndroidRuntime(30867): Falling back to OpenGL
E/AndroidRuntime(30867): TfLiteGpuDelegate Invoke: GpuDelegate must run on the same thread where it was initialized.
E/AndroidRuntime(30867): Node number 105 (TfLiteGpuDelegateV2) failed to invoke.
E/AndroidRuntime(30867): 
E/AndroidRuntime(30867):    at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.run(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(30867):    at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.run(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:158)
E/AndroidRuntime(30867):    at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(Interpreter.java:343)
E/AndroidRuntime(30867):    at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.run(Interpreter.java:304)
E/AndroidRuntime(30867):    at com.apptec.scansdk.MainActivity$RunSegmentationOnBinary.runTflite(MainActivity.java:237)
E/AndroidRuntime(30867):    at com.apptec.scansdk.MainActivity$TfliteTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:310)
E/AndroidRuntime(30867):    at com.apptec.scansdk.MainActivity$TfliteTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:284)
E/AndroidRuntime(30867):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
E/AndroidRuntime(30867):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
E/AndroidRuntime(30867):    ... 4 more
```

Here is my code to load model

```
MappedByteBuffer buffer = null;
        buffer = FileUtil.loadMappedFile(context, "docScan.tflite");
int numThreads = 4;

boolean useGpuDelegate = true;
final Interpreter.Options tfliteOptions = new Interpreter.Options();

tfliteOptions.setNumThreads(numThreads);
if (useGpuDelegate){
    GpuDelegate delegate = new GpuDelegate();
    tfliteOptions.addDelegate(delegate);
}
tfLite = new Interpreter(buffer, tfliteOptions);
```

Strangely, it works on phones like MI/Redmi/OPPO and only crashes on Samsung. Please help!

Comment: Do you have a switch widget to change between Cpu and Gpu?

Comment: @Farmaker No. Can you please share an example to do this. Thanks

Comment: Check this out with a switch https://github.com/farmaker47/video_style_transfer

Comment: Every instance needs to begin in a background thread

Answer (score 0):

The error which is thrown is your solution
**You have to run your Classifier and It's initialization on same thread other wise it give you this error**
I got same error which is solved by
**in  kotlin:->**
Thread{
// your classifier initialization and code
}.start()

Answer (score -1):

Add the following lines to AndroidManifest.xml:

*Link for AndroidManifestGpu.xml*:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/java/AndroidManifestGpu.xml

```
<application  

    <uses-native-library
        android:name="libOpenCL.so"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-native-library
        android:name="libOpenCL-car.so"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-native-library
        android:name="libOpenCL-pixel.so"
        android:required="false" />

</application>
```

Add these dependencies to your build.gradle:

```
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-metadata:0.1.0-rc2'
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:2.8.0'
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.1.0'
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-task-vision:0.1.0'
implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-task-text:0.1.0'
```

Comment: The error is caused by using the wrong thread not by missing libraries.

Comment: This actually fixed the issue for me. As you find in the documentation in the above link Apps targeting S+ need to add this in the manifest